# Bash exit and process substitution

Tags: bash, process-substitution

I would like to exit from a script if a function fails. Normally this is not a problem, but it becomes a problem if you use process substituion.

```sh
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

foo(){
  [ "$1" ] && echo pass || exit
}

read < <(foo 123)
read < <(foo)
echo 'SHOULD NOT SEE THIS'

$ ./test.sh
SHOULD NOT SEE THIS
```

Based on [**CodeGnome’s answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11622465) this seems to work

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

foo(){
  [ "$1" ] && echo pass || exit
}

read < <(foo 123) || exit
echo 'SHOULD SEE THIS'
read < <(foo) || exit
echo 'SHOULD NOT SEE THIS'

$ ./test.sh
SHOULD SEE THIS
```

Comment: Hint: your construction of foo doesn't evaluate to what you think it does. As written, your foo function will always return true. You probably wanted foo to contain `{ test -n "$1" && echo pass; } || exit 1` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set -e` to exit the script on any failure. This is often sufficient on smaller scripts, but lacks granularity.

You can also check the return status of any command or function directly, or inspect the `$?` variable. For example:

```
foo () {
  return 1
}

foo || { echo "Return status: $?"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `$?` will contain the exit code of `read`, not `foo`. If it is important to get `foo`'s exit code, I think you'll just have to avoid process substitution.

Comment: Doesn't this only work because `read` returns non-zero on EOF? I think in the general case, process substitution will not fail the parent command even with `errexit`.